# Flutter Bottom Nav Bar Static issue

Tags: flutter

I'm working with Flutter and have come across an issue with a "Only Static members can be accessed in Initializers".

I want to pass a string from one class to another, it is a UID I am trying to pass. I found a method to do it, but the only thing having an issue is the bottom navigation bar var list of pages. Here is the code:

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key, this.uid}) : super(key: key);
  final String uid;
  @override
  _ProfilePage createState() => _ProfilePage(uid);
}

class _ProfilePage extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {

  final String uid;
  _ProfilePage(this.uid);
  @override
  void initState() {
     super.initState();
  }

  int i = 2;
  var pages = [
    new LearningRoom(),
    new BrandRanking(),
    new Profile(uid), //Error is here with this
    new FabricCalculator(),
    new LookBook()
  ];
```

Would anyone be able to provide some help on solving this issue please? I've had a look around for about an hour and m unable to find anything that helps, I've tried converting to a method etc.

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: do not use `_ProfilePage(this.uid);`constructor  - simply remove it and use `widget.uid` inside your `State` class, and as for `pages` - initialize it inside `initState()` method

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `pages` creation in `initState()`.
Also do not use a new variable in `_ProfilePage`. You can just access `uid` by using `widget.uid` :

```dart
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key, this.uid}) : super(key: key);
  final String uid;
  @override
  _ProfilePage createState() => _ProfilePage(uid);
}

class _ProfilePage extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    int i = 2;
    var pages = [
      LearningRoom(),
      BrandRanking(),
      Profile(widget.uid),
      FabricCalculator(),
      LookBook()
    ];
    super.initState();
  }
```

Note : `new` keywords are not mandatory with Dart 2

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing the pages inside the **initState** method

```
class _ProfilePage extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {

  final String uid;
  var pages;
  _ProfilePage(this.uid);

  @override
  void initState() {
     super.initState();
     pages = [
      new LearningRoom(),
      new BrandRanking(),
      new Profile(uid), //Error is here with this
      new FabricCalculator(),
      new LookBook()
  ];
  }
```